# Tumblr Photoset Not Shown

Tags: html, tumblr, tumblr-html

The theme I have chosen does not display photosets on the index. Instead, it shows a link to the permalink with title "View Photoset." How do I go about changing the code so that either the photoset is spread out and shown, or the first photo in the photoset is shown?

Attached are the code dealing with photosets and a screenshot:

```
{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="misc_post">
  <span class="misc_title"><a href="{permalink}" target="_blank" title="Permalink">
  <u>View Photoset</u>
  <Br> {notecountwithlabel} </a>
  {block:RebloggedFrom} 
  &nbsp;/&nbsp;<a href="{ReblogParentURL}">
  Via: {ReblogParentName}</a> {/block:RebloggedFrom}
  </span>
</div>{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}
</center>
{/block:Photoset}
```

[image: photoset]